# React Stop Lazy Loading From Loading External Libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a system to have different templates being loaded in React, and currently I have a module being lazy loaded in React as such:

```
//import Template from "./templates/esports";
import React from "react";
import { lazy } from "react";

let Template = null;

let template_dir = './templates/esports/index.js';

if (template_dir) {

  Template  = React.lazy(() => import(`${template_dir}`));

} else {
  Template = require('./templates/error').default;
}


function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Template />
    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

This works if the template being loaded doesn't have any external libraries. For example, lets the file structure of the template is:

```
index.js
assets/js/jquery.js
assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js
```

The lazy loading will try to load the isotope and give an error as such:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/templates/esports/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/Users/me/Development/opensource/esports/frontend/src/templates/esports/assets/js'
```

How can I prevent these files being loaded? Or what is the correct way for loading these files dynamically?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why do you even need jQuery in React? Aside from that I think that if you just import those deps where they are used, it will have the same effect.

Comment: hm. Works on my machine. Unless I don't understand something, or my assumptions were wrong, e.g. what the paths in the `require` statements inside the imported modules are.